# Maven with Kotlin 1.2 : A required class was missing kotlin/reflect/KDeclarationContainer

Tags: java, maven, kotlin

I tried to use Kotlin with Maven so I followed the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html)

I have this configuration in the `pom.xml` file

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <kotlin.version>1.2.10</kotlin.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The sources folders are `src/main/kotlin` and `src/test/kotlin`

When I do `mvn clean install` I got this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.2.10:compile (compile) on project kotlin-starter: Execution compile of goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.2.10:compile failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.2.10:compile: kotlin/reflect/KDeclarationContainer
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.2.10
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
...
```

I also tried using `kotlin-stdlib` instead of `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` but I got the same error. When I open the library I see the class`KDeclarationContainer` in the package `kotlin.reflect` so I don't understand why I got this error ?

**EDIT** : when I change kotlin version to `<kotlin.version>1.1.61</kotlin.version>`, everything works perfectly...

Comment: What is your maven version? Do examples from https://codeload.github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/zip/master build?

Comment: my maven version is `3.5.2`. I already tried your example, it works but in the example kotlin version is really old `1.0.3`. when I tried your example with kotlin version `1.2.10` it doesn't work

Comment: Just created test project using maven 3.5.2. Pasted your pom file from above, and created a simple Kotlin file in src/main/kotlin. Compiles without issue. Successfully did 'mvn clean install'. Perhaps something isn't getting resolved correctly by Maven when you're building, and you're getting an older dependency?

Comment: @Mikezx6r my dependicies are fresh ones, what is your java version ? mine is 1.8.0_151

Comment: Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T03:58:13-04:00)
Java version: 1.8.0_152, vendor: Azul Systems, Inc.

On OSX Sierra

Comment: Tried changing the kotlin version in pom file to 1.1.61, failed with same error.

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar issue with kotlin-maven-plugin/1.2.20 which went away after I deleted org/jetbrains out of my local maven repo and re-ran the build. I can only think something was corrupted or missing.

Comment: I'm using Kotlin 1.2.51 and I have the same issue. The project compiles fine in IntelliJ though.
Deleting org/jetbrains didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Ditto here, deleted and re-run reproduced the same error.

Comment: `rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin` and rebuilding worked great with 1.6.0.